# combinatorics design

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

Six scientists are working on a secret project. They wish to lock up the documents in a cabinet so that the cabinet can be opened when and only when three or more of the scientists are present. What is the smallest number of locks needed? What is the smallest number of keys each scientist must carry?

I am thinking of solving this problem is this way:
Suppose there are n locks and label the keys with 1,2,...,n.

Let $X=\{1,2,...,n\}$. We have to construct six non-empty subsets of $X$, say, $A_1,A_2,...,A_6$ such that

1. $A_i \cup A_j \cup A_k = X$ for distinct $i,j,k$;and
2. $A_i \cup A_j \ne X$ for $i \ne j$.

From here I don't know how to proceed.
Any help will be much appreciated!

Best regards,Michael.

Comment: Hint:  given any two of the scientists there must be a lock such that A. Neither of those two has the key and B.  Each of the missing four has the key.

Comment: The smallest number of locks needed is six, with each scientist carrying one key and a complicated bolt system. What unstated assumptions / requirements do you have about the design of the cabinet?

Comment: If there are $n$ scientists and the safe can be opened only if $m$ or more are present, then the minimum number of locks required is $\binom{n}{m-1}$ and each scientist should have $\binom{n-1}{m-1}$ keys. See Challenging Mathematical Problems with Elementary Solutions, by A.M.Yaglom and I.M.Yaglom (Dover publications).

Comment: @Muralidharan,can you tell me the page and which volume of the books that contains this problem?

Comment: @luimichael Vol I, Problem 9, answer on page 49.

Comment: @luimichael Please consider accepting my answer if it suits you, thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

Building on lulu's hint :

For each couple of scientists, there must be a lock they don't have the key for and every other scientists got the key.

How many $c$ couples of scientists can we pick with a group of $6$ scientists ?

$$ c = {6\choose 2} = {6!\over 2!\cdot 4!} = 15$$

So the minimum number of locks is $15$.

From there you just have to pick every single couples of scientists and give a key to the $4$ other scientists.

Here is an example of what is might look like :

- Scientist 1 : $6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15$
- Scientist 2 : $ 2,3,4,5,10,11,12,13,14,15$
- Scientist 3 : $1,3,4,5,7,8,9,13,14,15$
- Scientist 4 : $1,2,4,5,6,8,9,11,12,15$
- Scientist 5 : $1,2,3,5,6,7,9,10,12,14$
- Scientist 6 : $1,2,3,4,6,7,8,10,11,13$

First step : we consider the couple $(\text{scientist }1,\text{scientist }2)$ and give the key to lock $1$ to every other scientists.
Then we repeat for the couple $(\text{scientist }1,\text{scientist }3)$ and so on ...

You can check that every couple of scientists is always missing a single key and that every other scientists got that key.

Comment: Given that there are $15$ locks and four scientists have a key to each of these locks, there must be $4 \cdot 15 = 60$ keys.  Since $60 \div 6 = 10$, each scientist should have $10$ keys.  To see why, pick a scientist.  Given any key that scientist has, there must be two other scientists who do not have that key.  Hence, each scientist must have $\binom{6 - 1}{2} = \binom{5}{2} = 10$ keys.